# how to match partial string from a text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data frame looks like -

```
id                               text
1         good,i am interested..please mail me.
2         call me...good to go with you
3         not interested...bye
4         i am not interested don't call me
5         price is too high so not interested
6         i have some requirement..please mail me
```

I want the data frame looks like -

```
id                               text                          is_relevant
1         good,i am interested..please mail me.                    yes
2         call me...good to go with you                            yes
3         not interested...bye                                      no
4         i am nt interested don't call me                          no
5         price is too high so not interested                       no
6         i have some requirement..please mail me                   yes
```

I have done the following code -

```
d1 = {'no': ['Not interested','nt interested']}
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}
df["is_relevant"] = df['new_text'].map(d).fillna('yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

In [21]: a
Out[21]: ['not interested', 'nt interested']

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   id                                     text
0   1    good i am interested..please mail me.
1   2            call me...good to go with you
2   3                     not interested...bye
3   4        i am not interested don't call me
4   5      price is too high so not interested
5   6  i have some requirement..please mail me

In [23]: df["is_relevant"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: "no" if (a[0] in x.lower() or a[1] in x.lower()) else "yes")

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   id                                     text is_relevant
0   1    good i am interested..please mail me.         yes
1   2            call me...good to go with you         yes
2   3                     not interested...bye          no
3   4        i am not interested don't call me          no
4   5      price is too high so not interested          no
5   6  i have some requirement..please mail me         yes
```

Comment: suppose my text is like "Thanks but no thanks"..now i include i "Thanks but no thanks" in my list i.e. a = ['not interested', 'nt interested','Thanks but no thanks']...its give me is_relevant = yes which is not correct...because list may be 100 or 1000.

Comment: @JohnDavis You have to lowercase `'Thanks but no thanks` in the list

Comment: can we need to modify this part? if (a[0] in x.lower() or a[1])...because it capture only 1st two words..already done lowercase "Thanks but no thanks"

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
d1 = {'no': ['not interested','nt interested']}

# create regex 
reg = '|'.join([f'\\b{x}\\b' for x in list(d1.values())[0]])

# apply function
df['is_relevant'] = df['text'].str.lower().str.contains(reg).map({True: 'no', False: 'yes'})

   id                                     text is_relevant
0   1    good,i am interested..please mail me.         yes
1   2            call me...good to go with you         yes
2   3                     not interested...bye          no
3   4        i am not interested don't call me          no
4   5      price is too high so not interested          no
5   6  i have some requirement..please mail me         yes
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to YOLO's answer above but allows for multiple text classes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = ["good,i am interested..please mail me.",
            "call me...good to go with you",
            "not interested...bye",
            "i am not interested don't call me",
            "price is too high so not interested",
            "i have some requirement..please mail me"],
    columns=['text'], index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])

d1 = {'no': ['Not interested','nt interested','not interested'],
      'maybe': ['requirement']}
df['is_relevant'] = 'yes'

for k in d1:
    match_inds = reduce(lambda x,y: x | y,
                        [df['text'].str.contains(pat) for pat in d1[k]])
    df.loc[match_inds, 'is_relevant'] = k

print(df)
```

Output

```
   text                                    is_relevant
1    good,i am interested..please mail me.         yes
2            call me...good to go with you         yes
3                     not interested...bye          no
4        i am not interested don't call me          no
5      price is too high so not interested          no
6  i have some requirement..please mail me       maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is what is in the list `['not interested', 'nt interested']`.

If the values are in ad dict, send them to a list as follows `lst=list(dict.values())` and still `np.where`

Then just `np.where`

```
lst=['not interested', 'nt interested']
df['is_relevant']=np.where(df.text.str.contains("|".join(lst)),'no','yes')

                                     text    is_relevant
1    good,i am interested..please mail me.         yes
2            call me...good to go with you         yes
3                     not interested...bye          no
4        i am not interested don't call me          no
5      price is too high so not interested          no
6  i have some requirement..please mail me         yes
```

Comment: See my attempt. I believe it is the fastest